# What are the GIT versions supported by GITLAB?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-8

I just started to use GITLAB.
Version of GITLAB is 8.7.5-ee.
I wanted to know what are all the GIT version supported and unsupported by GITLAB.

I will try to elaborate:

On my PC, I have GIT version 1.5/1.6, does GITLAB 8.7.5-ee supports this version?

I tried to get this information but I could not find.

Can some has this information, could you please provide in the form of chart or links?

Thanks and Regards,
Vijay Reddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted GITLAB support team for more information on the supported versions of GIT with GITLAB.

They confirmed that, All git versions(1.5 or 1.7...) are supported by GITLAB unless GIT LFS is used. Support Team also informed that they didn't receive any sort of questions related to this.

I have asked this since LINUX with redhat 7 and 8 comes with inbuilt GIT versions 1.7 and 1.8 respectively. These are officially supported version of GIT from redhat. So now with the confirmation, it is not required for the upgrade of GIT versions of Linux machines.

Regards,
Vijay Reddy.

Answer (score 0):

In their official [installation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#1-packages--dependencies) page they suggest >= 2.7.4:

> (...) Make sure you have the right version of Git installed
>
> ```
> # Install Git
> sudo apt-get install -y git-core
>
> # Make sure Git is version 2.7.4 or higher
> git --version
> ```

But you can try with an older one.